# How do I collect form data and add it to a database only redirecting on success?

Tags: javascript, html, go, redirect

I am setting up routing and a database for my API and I am having issues linking my front end logic with my backend logic. Essentially I want to POST form data and check all of it in the backend and redirect to a new page if it is successful.

I have tried using e.preventDefault() in the front end except that stops the POST request from going to the backend regardless of success of not.

Here are my Request handlers in my main function:

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/signup", signupHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/registered", registeredHandler)
```

Here is the actual handler functions:

```golang
func signupHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "signup.html", nil)

    fmt.Printf("METHOD: %s | URL: %v\n", r.Method, r.URL)
    fmt.Printf("User Visting Signup Form\n")
}

func registeredHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.html", nil)
    fmt.Printf("METHOD: %s | URL: %v\n", r.Method, r.URL)
    r.ParseForm()
    f := r.PostFormValue("fname")
    l := r.PostFormValue("lname")
    e := r.PostFormValue("email")
    pw := r.PostFormValue("pass")

    hash, err := helper.HashPassword(pw) // returns byte slice use conversion
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Hashing Error")
    }

    fmt.Println("LoginValues")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n, %s\n, %s\n, %s\n", f, l, e, hash)
}
```

HTML signup form signup.html (localhost:8080/signup):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/signup-styles.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="../static/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
   <title>Register</title>

   <div class="container">

      <img src="../static/img/logo.png" alt="logo">

      <form action="/registered" method="post">
         <h3>First Name</h3>
         <input name="fname" type="text" class="firstName">
         <p class="firstNameError"></p>
         <h3>Last Name</h3>
         <input name="lname" type="text" class="lastName">
         <p class="lastNameError"></p>
         <h3>Email</h3>
         <input name="email" type="text" class="email">
         <p class="emailError"></p>
         <h3>Create Password</h3>
         <input name="pass" type="password" class="createPassword">
         <p class="createPasswordError"></p>
         <h3>Verify Password</h3>
         <input type="password" class="verifyPassword">
         <p class="verifyPasswordError"></p>
         <button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>

   </div>

</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="../static/js/signup.js"></script>
</html>
```

front end javascript logic:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    if (/^\s+$/.test(firstName) || firstName == null || firstName == '') {
        document.querySelector('.firstNameError').innerHTML = 'First Name is a required field'
        document.querySelector('.firstName').style.borderBottom = '1px solid red'
    // There a ton more if/else doing front end form validation
    ...
}
```

I would've assumed the post request still would've worked since I had a handler for that route, except the e.preventDefault() completely stops the post from happening. I have taken away the preventDefault and the post request works fine but the issue is even if the form is NOT valid on the front end the form will still post.

Comment: I don't know Go, but the general solution for this problem is that HTML Forms just are designed to go to a new page when you submit.  If you replace your submit button with one that triggers a JS function, you could use that function to collect the values of your form and then AJAX them to a backend script. Your backend script can both validate it and save it to your DB. Then it and returns a response to your page to let it know if you succeeded or failed validation.  That response is then loaded into a placeholder as innerHTML without a full page reload.

Comment: What happens if you move e.preventDefault below all of your validation and execute it only if the validation failed? E.g. `if (form.isNotValid()) { e.preventDefault() }`

Comment: @mkopriva the issue is more that I want to validate everything again on the backend before I just throw everything into a database and redirect the user instantly. I think your solution would still kind of be validation on the front end which is not an issue. The form wont submit if the user doesn't have a valid email, matching password ect...

Comment: @JakeGoldstein Hi, my question is can you do some sort of front end validations byusing the jquery form validator.I think it will work fine in your case. http://www.formvalidator.net/

Comment: @ASHWINRAJEEV how so? we are doing form validation on the front end but even so I still want to ensure on the back end before I send things off to a database or redirect the user. The main issue here is the use of the e.preventDefault() in the javascript because once I comment that line out the form makes the post request. Except I kind of need that javascript because it allows for a smooth validation on the front end except it blocks the POST request from happening. I know this because I tried to handle different methods within my signupHandler and I would only be able to see the GET.